# I want copy-paste menu not spellcheck menu when right-clicking on selection

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, context-menu

In Windows, whether Outlook:edit-email or Word,

Let's say my paragraph has the word *customr*, where *customr* is the name of a variable in an app, that I am using Word to document, or using Outlook to communicate its issues.

So, I selected *customr* with my mouse, then right-click on the selection, hoping to copy the text.

But, no, the copy context-menu does not come up. Instead, the spellcheck menu comes up suggesting that I correct the text *customr*.

How can I persuade Word or Outlook to let me get the copy-paste context-menu?

The unacceptable kluge is over-selecting to include the space or full-stop (or any char) character before/after it. That is unacceptable because, now I have to do extra work removing that extra space, full-stop or newline which is a huge impediment to speed-typing. Also, double-clicking does not do over-selecting.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> keyboard shortcut instead of context menu or click the *Copy* button on the Outlook ribbon. Or just disable spellchecking.